# Finding suitable basis for a free abelian finitely generated group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-categories, finitely-generated

I am stuck with this exercise forever... I was barely taught about it, English is not my mother language and in any other phrasing it is not coherent with my material.I'd really appreciate your help. 
What I know is that $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is a basis of a free, finitely generated abelian group. There is a subgroup $B$ generated by $\{2e_1+3e_2,2e_1+6e_2\}$. I have to find a basis ${f_1,f_2}$ and positive integer $d_1|d_2|\cdots|d_r$ such that $\{d_1f_1, \cdots ,d_rf_r\}$ is a basis of $B$. In an example a teacher gave us, with other data(I will explain what he did with the data of this exercise instead.), he built a homomorphism from $f:\mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow A$, such that $f(1,0)=2e_1+3e_2, f(0,1)=2e_1+6e_2$. Im$f$ is of course $B$. Then classifying the columns of the matrix that represents the homomorphism according to $\{e_1,e_2\}$. In his example it would work well, but not here. I am frustrated. I'd like your help. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you know how to apply Smith's algorithm to obtain the factors and the matrices?

Comment: I never heard of this algorithm, so obviously I don't know how to apply this, but thank you for mentioning it. :)  It's a progress. I shall look for it and try to work with it... I still would appreciate any kind of suggestion as for how to find such a basis...

Comment: It looks like I am taking the exact same course exactly a year later, as the question fits the one appearing on my homework, no one explained anything about Smith normal form to us, and I have no idea what do to.. (also your name fits the area :P). Let's hope the single answer here will help me get on my way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent $f$ as a matrix, and apply Smith's algorithm, which is essentially an analogue of Gaussian elimination. My teacher got me used to writing matrices by rows, so I will represent $f$ like so:

$ f =\begin{bmatrix}2 & 3\\2 & 6\end{bmatrix} \to  \begin{bmatrix}2 & 3\\0 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

In each step, I subtracted one row from another.  The first arrow is basically the statement: "if $\{2e_1+3e_2,2e_1+6e_2\}$ generates $B$, then so does $\{2e_1+3e_2,3e_2\}$." If you can understand why that is true, you will be well on your way to answering your problem :) .

EDIT: I'll leave this since someone thought it was useful, but it does not fully answer the question.

Comment: But $2$ does not divide $3$,so you have not completed the process.

Comment: Oops, I misread the problem and overlooked that requirement. I'll remove my answer if I can't fix it shortly.

Comment: Thank you for your time,Max. Giving thoughts is important for the process. Thank you for explaining me about the algorithm as well